# Disable FPC per website or store

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, full-page-cache

Does anyone know if there is a method to tell the system to not Full Page Cache a specific store or website? And just to be clear, using EE FPC out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

In `system.xml` create config value which can be configurable per store view:

```
<enabled translate="label">
    <label>Enable FPC</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</enabled>
```

Do not forget to set default value for it in `config.xml` to **1**.

Than in the `<frontend>` section register observer on `controller_action_predispatch` event:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                <method>processPreDispatch</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

Now create observer with `processPreDispatch` method where you can check config value and disable FPC.

```
public function processPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('path/to/enabled')) {
        // Tell Magento to 'ban' the use of FPC for current sore view
        $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->banUse('full_page');
    }
}
```

Clear all cache types.